# How to create computer-to-computer network on macOS Sonoma (2023+)

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I've followed the instructions to [Create a computer-to-computer network on Mac](https://web.archive.org/web/20221128205554/https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl98b9beb6/mac), set up a temporary, ad hoc Wi-Fi connection between your Mac and another device.

Unfortunately, enabling legacy networks doesn't cause a create menu item to appear.

Use case: I want to use Syncthing to sync files even when I have no internet (e.g. I'm on a flight).

There should be a "Create Network" menu item according to the Apple Support page.

[image: Screenshot of the Wi-Fi status icon in the menu bar]

Comment: Same problem here, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

They have hidden this option under **System Settings** -> **General** -> **Sharing** ->  **Internet Sharing**.

You then need to select from which interface to which interface you want to setup the sharing. You'll most likely want to select a wired interface as the source, and WiFi as the destination.

[image: internet sharing options]

(I swear I could select WiFi as the destination a minute ago... (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻)

When you select WiFi as the destination, the "Wi-Fi Options" button can be clicked, and there you'll see the usual WiFi hotspot options.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. You're sharing an **internet** connection from your iPhone here. I'm asking for `a computer to computer network`, even when I don't have internet. I tried this in the past, and it didn't work. The setting you're referring to has been there for a while.

Answer (score -1):

As a temporary solution to connect the 2 devices, I've connected my android and macbook device using an ethernet cable and 2 usb-c <-> ethernet adapters. After configuring static IPs, it works.

However, it's quite clunky! I'd prefer a computer-to-computer wireless network supporting multiple devices. I don't want to bring a network switch...

Same diagram as https://superuser.com/a/1655603.

Comment: Sounds like you still need some help. You may get it faster or better if you provide your progress as an update to your question rather than an answer.

Answer (score -4):

I found it! and it works like a charm ;)

https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-create-a-secure-ad-hoc-network-in-macos/

Thanks to Matt Moore!

https://www.makeuseof.com/author/matt-moore/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. They not only make for a bad user experience because people have to jump off-site for the actual answer, they also don't show up in search. Also, the answer becomes useless when the link breaks. So, please summarize the solution directly in the post and leave the link for reference, please.

Comment: Also, the linked article seems to recommend the solution the OP already tried, and which didn't work for him.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/343111)

Comment: That article you linked to seems like a bad idea. `sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice AdHoc lo0` and `sudo networksetup -setmanual AdHoc 192.168.1.88 255.255.255.255` means using the loopback port and changing the IP from `127.0.0.1` to something arbitrary. Any applications connecting to 127.0.0.1 will not hit the loopback anymore. Breaking local applications communicating.

Comment: @BenButterworth I just tried this, but replacing ```192.168.1.88``` with ```127.0.0.1```. That seems to work fine, and ssh'ing into ```127.0.0.1``` works (as opposed to with the proposed solution). Do you still see any problem with this?

Comment: @Martin, I've just tried it. The network is created and visible, but other devices cannot connect to it. It doesn't seem useful? Did you try it?

Comment: @BenButterworth You're right, it worked for me because I hadn't reset things properly and it was still using ```192.168.1.88```. I now have a little script that, when I want to use the ad hoc network, enables the dummy interface and changes its IP to ```192.168.1.88```, then blocks until I'm done and hit control-C, at which point it changes the IP back to ```127.0.0.1``` and disables the dummy interface. That works well enough for me. The only problem I found is that I have to recreate the dummy interface after every system upgrade.

Comment: You can create multiple interfaces with different ips. I do that and haven’t had a problem.